# Android Navigation Component - Hard to control lifecycle of Fragment (not sequence)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I use Navigation Component for my project. But, I'm hard to control lifecycle of Fragment.

I have twos Fragment A & B, and A navigation to B.

That is my log:

```
SplashFragment: onCreate()
SplashFragment: onCreateView()
SplashFragment: onViewCreated()
HomeFragment: onCreate()
HomeFragment: onCreateView()
HomeFragment: onViewCreated()
SplashFragment: onDestroyView()
SplashFragment: onDestroy()
```

Why? and How to make it to be sequenced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the lifecycle.
You have to memorize when lifecycle events happen under which cases.

Comment: Yes, but the lifecycle not sequence, so I feel difficult to handle some tasks related the lifecycle :(